# How can I bind inside this ControlTemplate?

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp, binding

I have a `ListView`, filled with a `List<MyListItem>` and I need to use a `ControlTemplate` to be able to change the effects when an item is selected. Now I have the problem that `{Binding MyProperty}` doesn't work inside of that `ControlTemplate`. How can I access the properties of `MyListItem` inside the template?

My XAML looks like this(simplified):

```
<ListView
        Name="ListView"
        Grid.Column="1"
        IsSwipeEnabled="False">

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Grid>
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myColoredText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Orange"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="myColoredText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Red"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                                <!-- Here I have my custom layout, removed for readability -->
                                <TextBlock
                                    Name="myColoredText"
                                    Foreground="Green"
                                    Text="{Binding MyProperty}"/><!-- This does not work -->

                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Here is the class behind this XAML:

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListView.ItemsSource = new List<MyListItem>()
        {
            new MyListItem("Title1", "SubTitle1"),
            new MyListItem("Title2", "SubTitle2")
        }
    }
}
```

and the MyListItem class:

```
class MyListItem
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public string MyOtherProperty { get; set; }

    public MyListItem(string myProperty, string myOtherProperty)
    {
        MyProperty = myProperty;
        MyOtherProperty = myOtherProperty;
    }
}
```

Smallest project with the problem:

[Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6bmybghjuq92ek/App3.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Your code work's fine for me the way it is.

Comment: Please provide MyListItem class code

Comment: @VMaleev Edited my question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the `TextBox`, use:

```
Text="{Binding Content.MyProperty, 
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

Comment: I get the error that `AncestorType` cannot be found on `RelativeSource`. I am creating a Universal Windows App.

Comment: Sorry, missed that tag... I'll edit the answer for better approach.

Comment: `RelativeSource` makes the `"DataContext"` of the binding to be the control itself, i.e. ListViewItem. So now the `ListViewItem.Content` proprety is available and will contain the object you set as the content of the item, so `MyProperty` is available.

Comment: Hay @XAMeLi, thank you so much buddy!
I searched and worked for the last 3 days and whatever I get regarding my issue online, every one has explained it with his own Philosophy,  but your this single line binding inside the Style has just worked for me... I can't give you more than +1, otherwise I would give you 100+. 
Thanks once again. God bless you! :)

Comment: @ZiaUrRahman glad it helped. Just one point - this will not work in `Style` but only in `ControlTemplate` (and maybe `DataTemplate`, but need to check that).

Comment: @XAMeLi Yeah it works in ControlTemplate ... and I have a List<Class> having many properties and Style wherein ControlTemplate embedded ... so it worked for me. Thanks once again.
Another Question :) that can we add Visualstates inside a ControlTemplate which already have ListViewItemPresenter insde in UWP... I tried but in vain.

Comment: @ZiaUrRahman regarding VisualStates - I'm not well versed using them, usually prefer triggers where possible so I can't help you with that. Sorry.

Comment: Amazing tip. Thank you @XAMeLi.

Comment: For UWP and data binding use: "{Binding MyProperty, ElementName=ContentDialogRoot, Mode=OneWay}" and set your contentdialog's name to be "ContentDialogRoot"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `{TemplateBinding}` expression when dealing with custom `ControlTemplate`s. This binds property values to any corresponding properties associated with a control instance.

```
<TextBlock Name="myColoredText"
           Foreground="Green"
           Text="{TemplateBinding MyProperty}" />
```

This will bind to directly to the specified instance property in your control. Since WPF/WinRT controls are `DependencyObjects`, `DependencyProperties` are commonly used:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyProperty",
        typeof(Boolean),
        typeof(ListViewItem),
        null
    );

public bool MyProperty
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
}
```

Then when declaring a new instance, one would populate this property as is standard in XAML:

```
<someNamespace:ListViewItem MyProperty={Binding ViewModelProperty} />
```

You can read more on the TemplateBinding markup expression at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc189062(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: Where would I put the `DependencyProperty` then? I can't put it inside my custom class, as it is not inheriting anything, it only stores a few properties. This class is only used to create a list of data to use in my `ListView`

Comment: This is bad solution because he will have to register every property of his template

Comment: But that's how custom control templates work! It actually sounds like you want to use a `DataTemplate` instead. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JamesWright can I put the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` code inside the `DataTemplate`? I can't seem to get it to work. I need it to change my layout based on what state the `ListItem` is currently in.

Comment: Replacing your invocations of `VisualStateManger.GoToState` with `VisualStateManger.GoToElementState` may do it, as you can target visual states that sit in another element. Let me know how this works for you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.gotoelementstate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't invoke anything on the VisualStateManager myself, I simply override the visual effects linked to each state. I added a project where the problem occurs to my question.

Comment: My apologies, I keep forgetting that you're targeting a framework control. Let me have a think and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Wpf supports binding only to properties, not to fields. So, you MyItemClass should be:

```
public class MyListItem { 
    public string MyProperty { get; set; } 
    public string MyOtherProperty { get; set; } 

    public MyListItem(string myProperty, string myOtherProperty) {         
        MyProperty = myProperty; 
        MyOtherProperty = myOtherProperty;  
    }
}
```

Hope,  it helps

Comment: Sadly this was a typo from me, so no solution there.

Comment: This code works for at least two people.  It looks like test project, so you could share the whole project where the issue is reproducable

Comment: @vrwim is MyListItem public?

Comment: I am trying to make a test project, but it crashes immediately... I will get back to you when I am able to create said project.

Comment: Added the project to my question.

Answer (score 0):

A `ControlTemplate` is typically used to define what a control should look like. It is therefore much easier to put your XAML into a `DataTemplate` and assign it to the `ListView.ItemTemplate` property instead. You can access all of your custom properties from the `DataTemplate`:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Name="myColoredText" Foreground="Green"
            Text="{Binding MyProperty}" /><!-- This will now work -->
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

You can also use a `DataTemplate` from the `ItemContainerStyle` property like this:

```
<Style x:Key="SomeStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Your:DataType}">
                <TextBlock Name="myColoredText" Foreground="Green"
                    Text="{Binding MyProperty}" /><!-- This will now work -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this, but then I can't set the foreground color from my `ControlTemplate`. I use this template to change the look when an item is selected.

Comment: Then move that code to the `DataTemplate`. Alternatively, and this is probably better anyway, try utilising the [`ItemContainerStyle` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle(v=vs.110).aspx). This is typically used for exactly what you want... styling the container of the data item.

Comment: I am currently using the `ItemContainerStyle` property to style this `ListViewItem`. The problem is I can't both use `{Binding MyProperty}` (only works in `DataTemplate`) and `ItemContainerStyle` to style the `ListViewItem` when it is selected or unselected... I either have default styling or no binding.