# How to bind ContentTemplate in a ListView in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, contenttemplate

I have simplified the problem a bit, but I need to change the style and ControlTemplate for a ListView item while still binding to the ListView ItemSource.

Here is my ListView definition:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfStrings}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyListViewItemStyle}"/>
```

And the ItemContainerStyle:

```
<Style x:Key="MyListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
     <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <DataTemplate>
                         <TextBlock x:Name="txtValue" Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
               </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```

The ItemSource of the ListView is of type: `List<string>`

I need the TextBlock (txtValue) to display an item through the Binding to the ItemSource.

The ListView contains the correct amount of items, but how do I bind the TextBlock?

> I need to do this in a WPF Universal Windows Platform application. I
>   tested the same code in a normal WPF windows application and the code
>   works correctly. But in the UWP application the ContentTemplate does
>   not bind correctly.

I am sure I am missing something simple.

Comment: Are you perhaps missing a comma after the word Binding? Also I think that you can miss out Mode for TextBox as it defaults to TwoWay

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
 <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                     <TextBlock x:Name="txtValue" Text="{Binding }" />
           </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
```

Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.

The root of a Template content section cannot contain an element of type 'System.Windows.DataTemplate'. Only FrameworkElement and FrameworkContentElement types are valid.

Comment: It does not have an effect. I still have the correct number of items in the ListView (so it is picking up the binding), but _txtValue_ still does not display any values.

Comment: Try to check bindings and styles, this example working fine for me. Maybe you need to change foreground for textblock.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is done for a WPF Universal Windows Platform (UWP) application using VS2015. I tested the same code in a normal WPF application and everything works as expected. That is probably why you got it working. Will update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182037/how-can-i-bind-inside-this-controltemplate). Still trying to figure out why it works, but it does.